# animation to UIImageView with different types using objective-c

Tags: ios

I need to give different types of animation in UIImageView.

Types of animation :-
1.shake
2.swing
3.Bounce
3.Expand
4.Hinge

I tried with this code:

```
CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
   [anim setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];
   [anim setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:M_PI/16]]; // rotation angle
   [anim setDuration:0.1];
   [anim setRepeatCount:NSUIntegerMax];
   [anim setAutoreverses:YES];
   [[imageView layer] addAnimation:anim forKey:@"iconShake"];
```

but in this code what is the key:@"iconShake" and also @"transform.rotation"

How to do

Comment: Question is good but what you have tried

Comment: i tried but not working

Comment: @julie, Can you post your code that you tried?

Comment: i have edited .please check.My question is what is key here used